# Putting logo image on the same line as my header tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the logo on the same line as my H1 header tag, it has a line running below it so i want the logo above the line. I've tried messing around with the order the HTML tags are, but i can't get the logo on the same line without messing up the centring of the H1.

I've tried putting the margin:0 on the H1 but still doesn't help.

Css below:

```
#dashTitle {
text-align: center;
font-family: Futura PT;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 0px;
position: center;
/*left:-129px;*/
top: 7px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 48px;


 }

#logoDash {
float: left;
width: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 10px;


 }
```

This is the HTML, i have tried to order the tags differently

```
 <header id="dashboardHeader">


        <h1 id="dashTitle">STOCK TAKE</h1>
        <asp:Image ID="logoDash" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/SBC_Logo.JPG" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <hr />


    </header>
```

Image of how the current header looks [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set `position:absolute;` to your logo and `top: 40px;` like this:

```css
#dashTitle {
text-align: center;
font-family: Futura PT;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 48px;
 }

#logoDash {
position:absolute;
width: auto;
top:40px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="dashTitle">
STOCK TAKE
</h1>
<img id="logoDash" src="http://via.placeholder.com/48x48"/>
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dashboardHeader {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.dashTitle {
  font-family: Futura PT;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.dash-line {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="dashboardHeader">
  <img class="logoDash" src="https://i.imgur.com/kmNpJ2z.png">
  <h1 class="dashTitle">STOCK TAKE</h1>
  <img class="logoDash" src="https://i.imgur.com/kmNpJ2z.png">
</header>
<hr class="dash-line">
```

1. I'm using Flexbox to keep all 3 elements within your `<header>` element.
2. I changed your IDs to classes (and in the CSS, that's why the `#` is now a `.`). Why?  Because there's no reason for that level of specificity in your CSS that I can see.  Use classes, not IDs.  Here's a link to some documentation on specificity -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
3. Here's an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/4fxgy3nb/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` for the image.

```css
#dashTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Futura PT;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  position: center;
  /*left:-129px;*/
  top: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
}

#logoDash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header id="dashboardHeader">


  <h1 id="dashTitle">STOCK TAKE</h1>
  <img id="logoDash" src="//unsplash.it/75/50/" />
  <label id="lblUserDetails"></label>

  <hr />


</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#dashboardHeader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

These three lines for your header will keep all three elements on a single line.

---

- **Display: flex;** (runs flexbox layout)
- **justify-content: space-around;** (sets even space around each element, you can adjust this with margin and such at your own preference
- **align-items: center;** (this centers each item within its own box, again.. your personal preference.

---

Flexbox allows for far easier adjustment of layout than position/float usage. Check out CSS tricks for some more info on it.